# Custom Record For suitelet Sublist -Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I have a requirement where i should display the details(values) of the custom record in the suitelet sublist.

Now i have to create a custom Record with two fields. One field would be bill payment and other field will have list of bills related to bill payment.

When i create a custom record what should be my field vaues's type?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to keep one field of type `List/Record` and Record option to "`Transaction`", and second field of type `Multiple Select` with record option to "`Transaction`".

Since, the fields can hold reference to any transactions I would recommend writing a `user event script` which would fire on create/edit and validate that the fields value are always correct.

Comment: Keep in mind that Multi Select field type is not available as Sublist Field so this will not work since details will be shown in a suitelet with sublist. Unless, the suitelet will iterate the values on multi select field and and generate a link html of all the transaction and put it in a inlinehtml field of the sublist.

Comment: In Suitelet i am planning to call the custom record in my sublist . The custom record has two field , one is list/record and other is multiselect. Will this also wont work?

Comment: To display multi select field best approach would be to programatically compute HTML with hyperlinks and then display the field value in sublist as `inlinehtml`

Comment: Yes the suitelet already fetches the list of  bill payments and the related bills . `searchSublist.addField('custpage_billpaymid_field', 'text', 'Bill Payment');
 searchSublist.addField('custpage_bill_field', 'textarea', 'Bill').setDisplayType('inline');`

Comment: Yes the code already fetches the list of  bill payments and the related bills into an array . `searchSublist.addField('custpage_billpaymid_field', 'text', 'Bill Payment');
 searchSublist.addField('custpage_bill_field', 'textarea', 'Bill').setDisplayType('inline');`  Now I have a  `Custom Record ` with two fields `custrecord_bill_payment` and `custrecord_bills` .  I am unsure how to use my custom records to show the bills and bill payments.